# How to get this specific masonry layout with isotope js (only one grid item off!)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm sure you've heard of isotope.js, but here's a link to part of the project: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Here's an image of the desired layout I'm going for:

[image]

Here's a codepen with as close to the layout as I can get: https://codepen.io/levijosman/pen/GdewvN

I've tried changing the order of your items (based on the layout width), switch to different layout modes (like Packery). As you can see I'm only one grid-item off from the intended layout. The layout has to be possible with isotope.js or is it simply not?

```
<h1>Isotope - masonry layout mode</h1>
<div class="container">
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>  
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>  
</div>

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 313.81px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}

.grid-item--width2 { width: 637.64px; }
.grid-item--height2 { height: 410px; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the main problem is in the `itemSelector` in the javascript; it should have `.grid-item` instead of `masonry`, like so:

```
$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 100, 
    gutter: 8
  }
});
```

Then it should flow as expected, and you'll just have to replace your `grid-item--height2` class with another `grid-item` `div` after the big box:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>  
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJmmej